# Is there any plugin which can paste a common content to my every post?

Tags: plugins, posts

I am using wordpress for my blog. My blog contains events details and in every post i want to start with "this information is exclusively provided by...." this statement and end with my "feedburner subscribe us box"

So what I am actually looking for is

```
<---My String--->
    MY Actual Post
<---My feedburner subscribe us code--->
```

this. Is there any plugin which can automatically add the common stuff to my post. Please help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need a plugin to do this. Just add a simple function to your *functions.php* file:

```
function my_content($content) {
  $content = 'My content before post' . $content . 'My content after post';
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','my_content');
```

If you don't want additional content to appear in your feed, use following function:

```
if( !is_feed() ) {
  function my_content($content) {
    $content = 'My content before post' . $content . 'My content after post';
    return $content;
  }
  add_filter('the_content','my_content');
}
```

Comment: thnx Max for helping me out... :)